# Mocha unit testing: where to create variables

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm just getting into unit testing for the first time. Using Mocha in Node as the testing framework. All the examples I've come across create variables inside the `it()`. Does it matter if they are created inside or outside of `it()`? For example, if I have multiple `it()`s inside a `describe()`, and I need the same mocked data across all of the `it()`s. I'd rather not re-create the same variable repeatedly, if possible.

```
describe ('MyClass', function () {
    let myObj = new MyObj // Mock data here
    it ('Should be...', function () {
        ....
    })
    it ('Should be...', function () {
        ....
    })
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's totally acceptable to have variables live outside of your individual `it` blocks, but it may not be appropriate depending on your use case.

For objects that you do not expect to change, `Object.freeze` is an option: `const myObj = Object.freeze(new MyObj)`.

If you expect your tests to change your object, you should use `beforeEach` to ensure that they are restored to the proper state; this will prevent your `it` blocks from polluting one another and avoid an unpleasant debugging journey.

For example:

```
describe('MyClass', function () {
  let myObj

  beforEach(() => {
    myObj = new MyObj()
  })

  it('changes myObj', () => {
    changeProp(myObj.sum)
    expect(myObj.sum).toEqual(4)
  })

  it('depends on myObj being the same', () => {
    expect(myObj.sum).toEqual(2)
  })
})
```

Alternately, you can eschew the fat arrow syntax and rely on the shared context between blocks in mocha:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  this.myObj = new MyObj()
})

it('changes myObj', function () {
  addTwo(this.myObj.sum)
  expect(this.myObj.sum).toEqual(4)
})

it('depends on myObj being the same', function () {
  expect(this.myObj.sum).toEqual(2)
})
```